# Function for handling dictionary data

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary data like below

```py
dictData  = [
    {'period': '2020-01-01', 'ratio': 83.83458},
    {'period': '2020-01-02', 'ratio': 81.95488},
    {'period': '2020-01-03', 'ratio': 100},
    {'period': '2020-01-04', 'ratio': 77.25563},
    {'period': '2020-01-05', 'ratio': 90.22556}
]
```

... and I want really to get `period` and `ratio` values without iteration.

```py
for i in list(range(0, 4)):
    dictData[i]['ratio'], dictData[i]['period']
```

Is there any function in Python? Thank U

If `period` long, it takes too long times.

Comment: You don’t have a dictionary, you have a *list* of dictionaries.

Comment: I think `NO`. It is a list of dicts, not just a dict that you can simply use `dict.keys()` or `dict.values()`. The list requires iteration.

Comment: Not related, but `for i in list(range(0, 4)):` is redundant. Just use `for i in range(4):`.

Comment: ```for i in range(4):``` it is work thnkU!

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to use function and not any loop thing like `for`, `while` you can use `pandas` for this task

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = [{'period': '2020-01-01', 'ratio': 83.83458},
...  {'period': '2020-01-02', 'ratio': 81.95488},
...  {'period': '2020-01-03', 'ratio': 100},
...  {'period': '2020-01-04', 'ratio': 77.25563},
...  {'period': '2020-01-05', 'ratio': 90.22556}]
>>> 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> df
       period      ratio
0  2020-01-01   83.83458
1  2020-01-02   81.95488
2  2020-01-03  100.00000
3  2020-01-04   77.25563
4  2020-01-05   90.22556
>>> df['period']
0    2020-01-01
1    2020-01-02
2    2020-01-03
3    2020-01-04
4    2020-01-05
Name: period, dtype: object
>>> df['ratio']
0     83.83458
1     81.95488
2    100.00000
3     77.25563
4     90.22556
Name: ratio, dtype: float64
>>> 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> df['ratio'].to_list()
[83.83458, 81.95488, 100.0, 77.25563, 90.22556]
>>> 
>>> df['period'].to_list()
['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-04', '2020-01-05']
>>>
```